# python program can not get the args from the launch.json of VSCode?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger, args

when I set the launch.json with `"args": [ "-s", "0","-g", "0",]`, I do not get the values as I want in the python program.

```
# python file
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-s', '--seed',
    type=int,
    help = 'Random generator seed.',
    default=1,
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-g', '--gpu',
    type=int,
    help='CUDA GPU id (-1 for CPU).',
    default=-1,
)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(args.seed)
print(args.gpu)
```

```
# launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: 当前文件",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": [
                "-s", "0",
                "-g", "0",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the output in the terminal.

```
Namespace(seed=1, gpu=-1)
1
-1
```

Now what I can do is modify the default value in the python program.But why can't I pass the args from launch.json? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That looks like it should work - what's the output when you print `sys.argv`?

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge Here is the output of `print(sys.argv)` 
`['c:/Users/lijianwei/Desktop/1/t.py']`

Comment: Ok yeah the program straight up isn't receiving arguments then

Comment: How are you launching the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the image shows,
You should click the button "run" in the "run and debug" page(on the left side), Not click the run button on the top right of the page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS82U.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).